# How to optimize my query to not reach max time execution time?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a temporary table with 100k rows. It comes from a csv file and I use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to put it in temporary table and I need to process those raw data because it has duplication. So I make 3 tables which are product, product_images and product_description to process the raw data and put it there.

My sample code:

**Insert Raw Products to products table**

```
$data = $this->getRawDistinct(); // raw data I used sql group by here and get 2000 data
$insertedID = [];
foreach (array_chunk($data, 1000) as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $value) {
        $this->db->insert("{$this->prefix}products", [
            'name' => $value['product_title'],
            'brand_name' => $value['brand_name'],
            'brand_logo' => $value['brand_logo_image'],
            'status' => $value['product_status'],
            'keywords' => $value['keywords'],
        ]);

        array_push($insertedData, $this->db->insert_id); // store inserted data id
    }
}
```

**Insert Raw Products to product_image and product_description**

```
$processedProduct = $this->db->get_results(
    "SELECT id, name " . 
    "FROM {$this->prefix}products " . 
    "WHERE id IN ( ".implode(",", $insertedData)." ) "); // Get the data of those inserted earlier

foreach ($processedProduct as $key => $value) {
        $rawProducts = $this->db->get_results(
            "SELECT * " . 
            "FROM {$this->prefix}raw_products " . 
            "WHERE product_title = '$value->name'");
        if($rawProducts) {
            foreach ($rawProducts as $rawProduct) {
                //insert to product_image
                $this->db->insert("{$this->prefix}product_images", [
                    'product_id' => $value->id,
                    'thumbnail' => $rawProduct->thumbnail_image,
                    'color_swatch' => $rawProduct->color_swatch_image,
                    'product_image' => $rawProduct->product_image,
                    'front_flat' => $rawProduct->front_flat,
                    'back_flat' => $rawProduct->back_flat,
                    'front_model' => $rawProduct->front_model,
                    'back_model' => $rawProduct->back_model,
                    'side_model' => $rawProduct->side_model,
                    'three_q_model' => $rawProduct->three_q_model,
                    'color_square_image' => $rawProduct->color_square_image,
                    'color_product_image' => $rawProduct->color_product_image,
                ]);
                //insert to product_descriptions
                $this->db->insert("{$this->prefix}product_descriptions", [
                    'product_id' => $value->id,
                    'size' => $rawProduct->size,
                    'piece_weight' => $rawProduct->piece_weight,
                    'piece_price' => $rawProduct->piece_price,
                    'dozen_price' => $rawProduct->dozen_price,
                    'case_price' => $rawProduct->case_price,
                    'piece_sale_price' => $rawProduct->piece_sale_price,
                    'dozen_sale_price' => $rawProduct->dozen_sale_price,
                    'case_sale_price' => $rawProduct->case_sale_price,
                    'inventory_key' => $rawProduct->inventory_key,
                    'size_index' => $rawProduct->size_index,
                    'catalog_color' => $rawProduct->catalog_color,
                    'price_code' => $rawProduct->price_code,
                    'catalog_color' => $rawProduct->catalog_color,
                ]);
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see at the code, I distinct the records at first and get 2k of data because those are the products that I need to put in the products tables.

Don't get consfused of 100k then it comes to 2k, the other records are duplicated because it creates another row for different sizes, color, images and etc which is pertaining to one product only. And those sizes, images I need it to insert in product_image and product_description which both should have 100k records.

Insert Raw Products to products table is working fine but the inserting the raw product to product_image and product_description it insert data but not all because I reach max time execution and I already increase that to 5mins but I don't like that because the user will just for 5mins and still not processing all the data. How can I optimize it and make it work? or even handle more larger data than I'm facing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the database do all the work.

Assuming that `products` has an autoincrement id field,and that each `product_title` has only one `brand name`, `brand logo`, `status`, and `keywords` value:

```
INSERT INTO products 
    SELECT DISTINCT product_title name, brand_name, brand_logo_image brand_logo, product_status status, keywords
    FROM raw_products
```

Now we should have a good products table with a `product_id` field (the autoincrement field).  Now, we need to create the relational tables `product_images` and `product_descriptions`.  (side note, do these have a 1:1 relationship with each other?  For the sake of argument I'll assume they don't and you've established that they need to be separate)

```
INSERT INTO product_images
    SELECT p.id product_id, r.thumbnail_image thumbnail, r.color_swatch_image color_swatch, r.product_image, r.front_flat, r.back_flat, r.front_model, r.back_model, r.side_model, r.three_q_model, r.color_square_image, r.color_produt_image
    FROM raw_products r
    LEFT JOIN products p ON r.product_title=p.name
```

The left join is the magic here.  For each row of raw products, the db will attempt to join the left joined table on the matching conditions.  If it finds a match, it joins it; if no match is found, it puts nulls for the table's fields.  (In this case there will be no rows with null values for products.)

Using the second insert as an example, it should be trivial for you to craft the third insert.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll try this. But how can I add the product_id which is not exist in raw_products instead in product tables only.

Comment: It worked @TimMorton but I insert almost 5k records only in the table, I need 95k more.

Comment: my original thought was use `raw_product_id` for `product_id`, but I overlooked the fact that the `raw_product_id` is an aggregated value and hence there is no one `raw_product_id` for an individual product.  That explains why you were matching by product title in your next step...  I'll rework my answer a bit.  I have no idea why you came up short on rows; that problem might fix itself.

Comment: @rojan, expanded my answer